# Two-finger scrolling/touch on Windows To Go (Windows 8.1) on MacBook Pro Retina

Tags: windows-8.1, touchpad, macbook-pro-retina

I installed Windows To Go (Windows 8.1) on a USB hard disk on my MacBook Pro Retina late 2013. I have already updated the Apple Multitouch driver. One finger click on the touchpad works fine but two-finger scrolling/click doesn't work.

How to enable scrolling and two finger click?